# Animate hide and show on Framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I’m trying animate the hide and show of a “scroll to top” button dynamically inserted

```
$('.content').append('<button id="scroll_to_top_btn" title="Go to top"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></button>');
            
            //Show Scroll to top button when scroll and hide when on top
            $('.page-content-news').on('scroll', function () {
              var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
              if(scrollTop > 0){
                  $('#scroll_to_top_btn').animate({'display': 'block'});
              }
              else{
                  $('#scroll_to_top_btn').animate({'display': 'none'});
              }
            })
```

But don't animate when I scroll the page (works fine with hide() and show())

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some styles.

```
#scroll_to_top_btn {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
#scroll_to_top_btn.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And add/remove the hide class instead of animate.

```
$('.content').append('<button id="scroll_to_top_btn" title="Go to top"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></button>');
            
//Show Scroll to top button when scroll and hide when on top
$('.page-content-news').on('scroll', function () {
  var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  if(scrollTop > 0){
    $('#scroll_to_top_btn').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#scroll_to_top_btn').addClass('hide');
  }
})
```